# Do complementary DNA sequences/codons produce the same amino acids?

Tags: molecular-biology, dna

I haven’t been able to confirm this anywhere. If this were not the case, when transcription occurred, if the transcription were based upon the incorrect side of the DNA molecule, a completely incorrect output would result. Complementary sides should be aliases of each other, but I have not been able to find anywhere whether this is the case.

Comment: Isn't this trivial to answer using a chart of the genetic code? How do you think transcription would start on the "wrong" side?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] to find information on what we do here. In particular pay attention to the [homework](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) policy, which would cover your question. You could self-answer your question by thinking about strandedness and direction of transcription!

Comment: @BryanKrause In the very least, in this image, the sequence UUU does not produce the same results as AAA: https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/3-s2.0-B9780128008836000112-f11-05-9780128008836.jpg

Comment: “Complementary sides should be aliases of each other” — are you assuming that complementary strands should produce the same proteins when transcribed and translated? Why do you believe this to be true?

Comment: If DNA intends to code for one set of amino acids, would it not be wrong for a ribosome to build a polypeptide from different amino acids than one side of the DNA molecule intended for? Essentially, if one side of the DNA molecule depends on the other side of the DNA molecule, why would it ever be the case that complementary sequences don’t produce the same amino acid outputs? Since DNA is symmetric, I don’t see how the ribosome would be able to determine which side is intended to hold the information, in the case that complementary bases within codons don’t code for the same bases.

Comment: @acvill Does the whole “DNA transcription to RNA to translation within the Ribosome” process have some way of determining which side of the DNA molecule was supposed to be read? Since DNA is supposed to be complementary throughout, if I wanted to store some sequence on one side, I wouldn’t be able to just continue on storing more information on the other side of the molecule- the other side would be reserved for a chemical mirror image of my stored information. If one side holds the desired code and the other simply holds the backup copy, I only intend for the desired side to be read- but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Transcription](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_(biology)) is a highly regulated process, cells aren't just producing random RNAs from random stretches of DNA.

The transcription machinery needs to bind to DNA to get started, which requires a promotor sequence. It's not necessary for DNA to "read" the same way forwards and back, because it'll only be transcribed in the correct direction.

Comment: My question is not about the direction of transcription and translation, but rather, which side of the molecule the process begins copying from (i.e. not along the molecule, but across to the mirror side). If one side’s sequence deterministically depends on the other’s, is it the case that either side (i.e. codons containing exactly complementary bases) would produce the same output? If not, then why? Is there some way of ensuring that only one side of the mirrored DNA structure is read?

Comment: Yes, only that side "fits". DNA is directional (the ends are referred to as 5' and 3' ends). If you read the whole Wikipedia page on transcription or an equivalent chapter in a biology textbook I think it'll become clear. If you wanted to transcribe the other side, you'd have to start at the "end" and work backwards.

Comment: Thank you. I think this directionality shows me where the cracks of my question lies.